# Naming a complex crud function

Tags: javascript, api, crud

I have a function below that does the following uses a bunch of smaller `CRUD` operations which I call `create`, `retrieve` (instead of `read`), `update`, `delete`. Because this function does a bit of everything it can be hard to name it.

Here's a bit about its behavior:

- pass in array of redirects (objects with `url`, and `path` properties)
- retrieves all existing redirects
- checks to see if requesting redirect path exists
- if existing redirect with path exists and url is the same returns existing
- if existing redirect with path exists updates redirect
- if existing redirect with path does not exist creates new redirect

Here are some possible candidates:

- `retrieveAllRedirectsUpdateExistingRedirectsCreateNewRedirectsDoNothingForRedirectsWithNoChange`
- `retrieveAllUpdateExistingCreateNewRedirects`
- `retrieveUpdateCreateRedirects`
- `ensureRedirectsExist`
- `ensureRedirects`
- `overwriteRedirects` // implies will delete redirects not passed to it
- `createRedirects`
- `redirects`

Here's the function:

```
Shopify.prototype.ensureRedirects = function(redirects){
  return this.retrieveAllRedirects().then(function(existingRedirects){
    return Promise.map(redirects, function(redirect){
      return Promise.resolve(existingRedirects).then(_).call("findWhere", {
        "path": redirect.path,
      }).then(function(match){
        if(match && match.url == redirect.url) return match
        if(match) return this.updateRedirect(match.id, redirect)
        return this.createRedirect(redirect)
      }.bind(this))
    }.bind(this))
  }.bind(this))
}
```

What naming convention lends itself to the most flexibility and follows the best pattern?

Other functions that I have in this library include but aren't limited to:

- `retrieveRedirects` (paginated)
- `retrieveRedirectsCount`
- `retrieveAllRedirects` (all pages)
- `createRedirect`
- `updateRedirect`

This also begs the question should this function above be `createRedirects` as an alias of `createRedirect` that detects `argument` type `object` v.s. `array` and creates the `redirects` accordingly, making the `createRedirect` function more versatile to handle argument types? Then what do you name the function and argument? [Convention for naming a function or variable as both plural and singular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482546/convention-for-naming-a-function-or-variable-as-both-plural-and-singular)

Comment: I believe this is what they call "over thinking it"

Comment: Could you add the language tag to your question? :)

Comment: Done it friend :)

Answer (score 1):

### Abstractions

When working with collections, there are three layers of functions - each essentially justifying a module:

```
  h(url[], url[]) -> url[]
  g(url, url[])   -> url[]
  f(url1, url2)   -> url
```

The dependencies are `h <- g <- f`. The functions at `f` are more reusable than those at `g` are more reusable than those at the highest level `h`.

### Complected.

I'll reflect my bias:  If a function is so complex it is hard to name, it might need to be refactored.

The place to start is with a function [let's call it `g`] that takes one item from `redirects` and modifies `existingRedirects` atomically. Then the existing function `ensureRedirects` can focus on operations at the level of the collection.

Conceptual mangling of the three levels - processing a collection of possible changes versus processing one possible change versus comparing two items - is clear from the description of the `ensureRedirects`'s behavior in the question. A lot of it is at the level of processing a single URL against a collection of URL's even though `ensureRedirects` operates on collections. Some of it is about dealing with two URL's.

The naming should flow from smaller pieces to larger pieces. Or `h` could just be `redirects.foreach(g)`